# Create links for all subdirectories

Tags: java, applet, japplet

Unfortunately I have no experience with Java but it seems that in this case without it not to manage... Faced such task: it is necessary in the HTML document, at its opening, dynamically to form a set of references which would indicate all files `../../bin/*/versionInfo.xml`

I.E. in the sub-directory bin there can be any number of catalogs, in each of which surely there is a file `versionInfo.xml`.

It is impossible to make it means of JavaScript (for safety reasons), and PHP doesn't approach, since it should be carried out by the client computer. Java plug-in at clients is established. I hope that by means of Java the task can be solved. 
I.E. such marking (provided that available the sub-directories version1-3) should be result:

```
<ul>
  <a href="../../bin/version1/versionInfo.xml">version1</a>
  <a href="../../bin/version2/versionInfo.xml">version2</a>
  <a href="../../bin/version3/versionInfo.xml">version3</a>
</ul>
```

I so understand that the code on Java placed in the applet element is necessary. I ask knowing people to help with a necessary marking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ..it should be carried out by the client computer.

An applet cannot achieve this without the server's help.  By 'help' I specifically mean the server returning a file list in some form.